# Get the IpAddress on which we received an UDP Multicast request

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, multicast, udpclient

I'm using an `UdpClient` to read data from a multicast group.

It's configured like this:

```
m_udpClientReceiver = new UdpClient();
m_receivingEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, m_port);
m_udpClientReceiver.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
m_udpClientReceiver.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
m_udpClientReceiver.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
m_udpClientReceiver.Client.Bind(m_receivingEndPoint);
m_udpClientReceiver.JoinMulticastGroup(m_multicastAddress, 255);
```

and I read it with:

```
Byte[] data = m_udpClientReceiver.Receive(ref m_receivingEndPoint);
```

I've several network cards(two LAN, one wifi), that are bound on differents subnets. I need to know on which network card(which ip in fact) the request has been received.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: i think that you can read it in the packet data/header

Comment: ? Where? The header will contains the multicast address

Comment: the udp checksum si calculated with the receiver ip address so it must be somewhere

Comment: Hi, maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890/how-to-get-your-own-local-ip-address-from-an-udp-socket-c-c

Comment: @ChristopherCabezudoRodriguez : It will not works with wifi+LAN networks on the same subnetwork.

Comment: After the call to `Receive`, `m_receivingEndPoint` will have the IP address of the remote (sending) host.  i.e. you've named `m_receivingEndPoint` wrong.

Comment: @PeterRitchie : Yeah I know, I'm already using this for another feature, but here, I don't need the remote  IP, I need the local IP on which I received this packet.

Comment: There's no way to know for sure, unless you bind to a specific IP when you create the `UdpClient`.  `UdpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint` would contain the local end point; but if you bound to "any", then that would be the end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally using the [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx) method(async), and I'm giving as context the ip on which it's bound

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative have you considered not joining a multicast group? You can send and receive multicast packets just as easily using the standard UDPClient class. i.e.

```
UdpClient.Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes, IPEndPoint endPoint)
```

where `endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, <port number>)`. And on the receive still using:

```
Byte[] data = m_udpClientReceiver.Receive(ref m_receivingEndPoint);
```

where m_receivingEndPoint is now correctly set? I've just tested this and it works fine.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I guess that if this method exists, it must do something more than the Receive method with the correct ref, no?