# Function to retrieve the header destination address from a packet in windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I am interested in retrieving the destination address that an inbound packet is sent to. For example on Linux you can utilize `recvmsg`:

```
res = recvmsg(socket, &msghdr, 0);
get_cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(msghdr);   
struct in_pktinfo *get_pktinfo = (struct in_pktinfo *)CMSG_DATA(get_cmsg);
printf(" - Header destination address (get_pktinfo.ipi_addr)=%s\n", inet_ntoa(pktinfo.ipi_addr));
```

*Steps have been skipped to save many many lines*

The key here is that `recvmsg` is easy to use. Similar functions are implemented for Windows XP like [`recvfrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120.aspx) but Windows does not seem to implement the `recvmsg` function.

Similarly named functions exist, like the [`WSARevcMsg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687.aspx) function, but according to the linked documentation it is only included in Windows Vista and above.

**Is there a way I can get the header destination address from a packet in Windows XP?**

---

*I know that using XP is bad and old, unfortunately we are attempting to fix a bug on a legacy product, so at this time we are unable to simply upgrade.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> windows does not seem to implement the recvmsg function.

Actually, it does (well, an equivalent, anyway):

[WSARecvMsg function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687.aspx)

> Similar functions have been revamped like the WSArevcMsg but these are only included in windows vista and above.

You can't always trust MSDN documentation.  When Microsoft officially drops support for a Windows version (like XP), it tends to remove references to that version from MSDN, including *"Minimum supported ..."* requirements of API functions (which annoys many programmers).  The key point is **supported**.  Microsoft does not *support* older Windows versions.

`WSARecvMsg()` was first introduced in XP, which was EOL'ed in 2014 and many references to it were stricken from MSDN documentation (here is [proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20131013073156/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741687.aspx) from 2013 when the `WSARecvMsg()` documentation stated XP and not Vista was the *"Minimum **supported** client"*).

---

As stated in the `WSARecvFrom()` documentation:

> **Note** The function pointer for the `WSARecvMsg` function must be obtained at run time by making a call to the [`WSAIoctl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621.aspx) function with the `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified. The input buffer passed to the `WSAIoctl` function must contain `WSAID_WSARECVMSG`, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value identifies the `WSARecvMsg` extension function. On success, the output returned by the `WSAIoctl` function contains a pointer to the `WSARecvMsg` function. The `WSAID_WSARECVMSG` GUID is defined in the *Mswsock.h* header file.

`WSAID_WSARECVMSG` is defined as:

```
#define WSAID_WSARECVMSG \
    {0xf689d7c8,0x6f1f,0x436b,{0x8a,0x53,0xe5,0x4f,0xe3,0x51,0xc3,0x22}}
```

aka `{F689D7C8-6F1F-436B-8A53-E54FE351C322}` in text format.

For example:

```
SOCKET sckt = ...;
LPFN_WSARECVMSG lpWSARecvMsg = NULL;

GUID g = WSAID_WSARECVMSG;
DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
if (WSAIoctl(sckt, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &g, sizeof(g), &lpWSARecvMsg, sizeof(lpWSARecvMsg), &dwBytesReturned, NULL, NULL) != 0)
{
    // WSARecvMsg is not available...
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
BYTE buffer[...];
DWORD dwBytesRecv;

WSABUF msgbuf;
memset(&msgbuf, 0, sizeof(msgbuf));
msgbuf.len = sizeof(buffer);
msgbuf.buf = (char *) buffer;

// call WSA_CMSG_SPACE() once for each option you enable
// on the socket that can return data in WSARecvMsg()...
int size = 0;
if (... IP_PKTINFO is enabled ...)
    size += WSA_CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct in_pktinfo));
if (... IPV6_PKTINFO is enabled ...)
    size += WSA_CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct in6_pktinfo));
// other packet options as needed...

BYTE *controlbuf = (BYTE *) malloc(size);

SOCKADDR_STORAGE *addrbuf = (SOCKADDR_STORAGE *) malloc(sizeof(SOCKADDR_STORAGE));

WSAMSG msg;
memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
msg.name = (struct sockaddr *) addrbuf;
msg.namelen = sizeof(SOCKADDR_STORAGE);
msg.lpBuffers = &msgbuf;
msg.dwBufferCount = 1;
msg.Control.len = size;
msg.Control.buf = (char *) controlbuf;

if (lpWSARecvMsg(sckt, &msg, &dwBytesRecv, NULL, NULL) == 0)
{
    // addrbuf contains the sender's IP and port...
    switch (addrbuf->ss_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) addrbuf;
            // use addr as needed...
            break;
        }

        case AF_INET6:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*) addrbuf;
            // use addr as needed...
            break;
        }
    }

    WSACMSGHDR *msghdr = WSA_CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    while (msghdr)
    {
        switch (msghdr->cmsg_type)
        {
            case IP_PKTINFO: // also IPV6_PKTINF
            {
                // must call setsockopt(sckt, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, TRUE) beforehand to receive this for IPv4
                // must call setsockopt(sckt, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_PKTINFO, TRUE) beforehand to receive this for IPv6

                switch (addrbuf->ss_family)
                {
                    case AF_INET:
                    {
                        struct in_pktinfo *pktinfo = (struct in_pktinfo *) WSA_CMSG_DATA(msghdr);
                        // use pktinfo as needed...
                        break;
                    }

                    case AF_INET6:
                    {
                        struct in6_pktinfo *pktinfo = (struct in6_pktinfo *) WSA_CMSG_DATA(msghdr);
                        // use pktinfo as needed...
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            // other packet options as needed...
        }

        msghdr = WSA_CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, msghdr);
    }
}

free(addrbuf);
free(controlbuf);
```

Comment: Any idea why we are getting `error C3861: 'WSARecvMsg': identifier not found` when using `WSARecvMsg` with `#define WINVER 0x501` (Win XP)? `Mswsock.h` is included, as per the documentation. We cannot see that in the source file?

Comment: @Ben: Read the `WSARecvMsg()` documentation more carefully.  I have added the relavant quote to my answer.  The `WSARecvMsg()` function itself is not declared in any header files.  You have to make your code declare a pointer variable of type `LPFN_WSARECVMSG` (which is defined in Mswsock.h) and then use `WSAIoctl()` to assign a function pointer to `WSARecvMsg()` to that variable, and then you can use that pointer to call `WSARecvMsg()` as needed.

Comment: Yep after reading it is clear, should have just read from start to finish.

Comment: Also yeah, many references to xp seem to have been removed but not all, which is even more annoying ...

Comment: Do we need to get the function pointer for `WSARecvMsg` every time we read? Is there any reason this function would change? Can we just get it once?

Comment: No, you do not need to retrieve the pointer every time you want to call it.  You can indeed retrieve it once and reuse it multiple times.

Comment: Since it wasnt easy to find this answerr i added the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355397/why-is-the-wsarecvmsg-function-implemented-as-a-function-pointer-and-can-this-po) so it will be well documented.

Comment: Is `WSA_CMSG_LEN` being used correctly in the above example?  It seems like you're taking the size of the entire message buffer plus 2 layers of `WSABUF` headers and allocating that whole size for the size of the Control buffer.  It should work, presumably, in most cases, but only because the packet buffer should be way bigger than Control data.  It seems like to me (for example) if you're receiving  `in_pktinfo` you should size your buffer to `WSA_CMSG_LEN(sizeof(in_pktinfo))` and if there's another option you should add `WSA_CMSG_LEN(sizeof(whatever))` to that.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MichaelPowell "*Am I mistaken?*" - probably not.  The above was taken from a socket library I work with, and that is how they allocate the control buffer.  After reading the documentation again, I think what you describe is probably correct, except that it should be using `WSA_CMSG_SPACE()` instead of `WSA_CMSG_LEN()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I've continued working on this since asking the question, came to the same conclusion, and was about to come back and say this very thing.  Thanks for your help, and for the otherwise invaluable example!  This is a really tricky piece of API.  Say hi to Rogue for me!