# Getting the destination IP of incoming UDP packet in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, udp, ip-address, packet

I found the function: [GetTcpTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable) in **C++**. In the header: **iphlpapi.h**. That gives me the **destination IP** of **TCP** packet and I was wondering if there's a function from the same header that would give me the **destination IP** of **UDP** packet... I tried the function: [GetUdpTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudptable) but it gives only the **local IP and port**. I will be more than happy if that function has also code example in  **C++** of course. **Thank you anyway!**

**EDIT:**
I using pcap.h now and i still don't know how to catch UDP packets and take from them the ip. There is a code that i can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetTcpTable()` does not give you the destination IP of TCP packets.  It merely gives you a list of currently listening TCP ports and active TCP connections.

`GetUdpTable()` can give you the list of currently listening UDP ports, where UDP packets can be sent to.  There are no connections in UDP.

But, if you want to know the actual destination IP for each UDP packet received, and without having to use a low-level capture library like WinPCap, then you can use the [`WSARecvMsg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms741687(v=vs.85)) function to receive your UDP packets, rather than using the `recvfrom()` or even `recv()` function.

`WSARecvMsg()` can report metadata about each packet, most notably the [`IP_PKTINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ip-pktinfo) (IPv4) and [`IPV6_PKTINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipv6-pktinfo) (IPv6) control blocks, which specify the destination IP of the packet and the index of the network interface that received the packet.

You need to use [`WSAIoctl(SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaioctl) to obtain a pointer to the `WSARecvMsg()` function (see [Why is the WSARecvMsg function implemented as a function pointer and can this pointer be reused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355397/) for the reason why), and use [`setsockopt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt) to enable the `IP_PKTINFO`/`IPV6_PKTINFO` socket option, before you start calling `WSARecvMsg()` to receive packets.

See [Function to retrieve the header destination address from a packet in windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334871/) for an example.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209972/discussion-on-answer-by-remy-lebeau-getting-the-destination-ip-of-incoming-udp-p).